# MySql not using an index

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb

DB  engine is MySql 8.
I am running a simple query on a table that has an index on id column however its not using the index and its doing a full table scan.

The table has statistics updated the column of id is int and the index is also on int.

I dont want to change the query and use force index and in Maria db it is using the index correctly.

Here is the explain plan:

```
1   SIMPLE  user_actions        ALL index_id                558242932   0.0 Using where; Using parallel query (2 columns, 1 filters, 1 exprs; 0 extra)
1   SIMPLE  user_actions        eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   db.user_actions.id  1   100.0
```

I have gathered stats and expected that the optimizer will use the index while the where clause is filtering by this column using " id in (3,5,7,34,56)

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT` in question.

Comment: And how many items in the id list?  And I think that MySQL and MariaDB will work differently (based on what little you have provided).

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table user_actions` and `select version();` (in mysql) and your full query.  This is necessary information to get meaningful responses.

Comment: Here is the create statement:
CREATE TABLE `perks_user_actions` (
  `perk_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_action_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `index_perks_user_actions_on_perk_id` (`perk_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci STATS_AUTO_RECALC=1

Comment: here is the query:
SELECT perks_user_actions.perk_id, `user_actions`.`type`
FROM `user_actions`
    INNER JOIN `perks_user_actions` ON `perks_user_actions`.`user_action_id` = `user_actions`.`id`
WHERE (perks_user_actions.perk_id IN (1320106789,1320107196,1320107205,1320140586,1320140629,1320140814,1320142062,1320144070,1320145009,1320145605,1320146248,1320146703,1320146735,1320146812,1320148062,1320148067,1320149834,1320151198,1320151805,1320152709,1320152729,1320153299,1320153873,1320155036,1320155458,1320156355))

Comment: Please include the CREATE in the Question.  And please have the CREATE and the SELECT match -- Are `perk_id` and `index_id` the same?

Comment: The table sounds tiny; but the EXPLAIN implies that it is huge.  The size of the table and the number of ids in the `IN` matter.  How many of each?

Comment: @RickJames the table is huge - 559350938
and the ids in the query are 26

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` and the output from Optimizer Trace.

Answer (score 1):

You never included your actual SQL query, but for the purpose of this answer, I will assume your query looks something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE id IN (3, 5, 7, 34, 56);
```

This is the same as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE id = 3 OR id = 5 OR id = 7 OR id = 34 OR id = 56;
```

Queries with `OR` conditions in the `WHERE` clause are hard to make amenable to index use.  Such a query will probably *not* use an index on `id`, because doing so would either require several index seeks for each value, or a single full index scan.  In either case, MySQL might just decide to scan the entire table, which is what your query plan seems to be saying.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what like what my quey looks like. But still I dont understand why not use an index and scan only 56 rows (when I force using index) and instead the optimized uses full table scan and scans ~500M rows ..

Comment: Check the EXPLAINs for the IN vs OR -- The Optimizer _may_ turn ORs into an IN.

Comment: @RickJames - thanks. I checked and for both its not using the index ... :(